# Java sliding JPanels

Tags: java, animation, slide, effects

I have a menu that has a variety of buttons on display, I'm able to make the buttons call their respective JPanels when clicked. The thing is I would like to make the Jpanel slide in when its called instead of instantaneously popping in. I tried using tween engine and as Java beginner,  I find it really overwhelming, so I decided to use timed animation.  I was able to make the Jpanel on top to slide to one side but for some reason the next panel doesn't want to display,  im really tired, can someone help please!  There code is below:

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                

              mainpane.setLocation(mainpane.getX() - 10, 0);
              if (mainpane.getX() + mainpane.getWidth() == 0) 
              {
                 ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                   System.out.println("Timer stopped");
              } 
           }
        }).start();   
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sliding panels can be tricky.  Here is some starter code.  Modify to fit 
your needs.  Add error checking and exception handling as necessary.

This example uses JButtons and a JTree as content but you can use just about any type of content.

[image: Example Slider]

Usage:

```
static public void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame() {
                {
                    final PanelSlider42<JFrame> slider = new PanelSlider42<JFrame>(this);
                    final JPanel jPanel = slider.getBasePanel();

                    slider.addComponent(new JButton("1"));
                    slider.addComponent(new JButton("22"));
                    slider.addComponent(new JButton("333"));
                    slider.addComponent(new JButton("4444"));

                    getContentPane().add(jPanel);
                    setSize(300, 300);
                    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    setVisible(true);
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

The impl is lengthy ...

```
package com.java42.example.code;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PanelSlider42<ParentType extends Container> {

private static final int           RIGHT             = 0x01;
private static final int           LEFT              = 0x02;
private static final int           TOP               = 0x03;
private static final int           BOTTOM            = 0x04;
private final JPanel               basePanel         = new JPanel();
private final ParentType           parent;
private final Object               lock              = new Object();
private final ArrayList<Component> jPanels           = new ArrayList<Component>();
private final boolean              useSlideButton    = true;
private boolean                    isSlideInProgress = false;

private final JPanel               glassPane;
{
    glassPane = new JPanel();
    glassPane.setOpaque(false);
    glassPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    });
    glassPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    });
    glassPane.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    });
}

public PanelSlider42(final ParentType parent) {
    if (parent == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("ProgramCheck: Parent can not be null.");
    }
    if ((parent instanceof JFrame) || (parent instanceof JDialog) || (parent instanceof JWindow) || (parent instanceof JPanel)) {
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("ProgramCheck: Parent type not supported. " + parent.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    this.parent = parent;
    attach();
    basePanel.setSize(parent.getSize());
    basePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    if (useSlideButton) {
        final JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
        basePanel.add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        statusPanel.add(new JButton("Slide Left") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 9204819004142223529L;
            {
                setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
            {
                addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                        slideLeft();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        statusPanel.add(new JButton("Slide Right") {
            {
                setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 9204819004142223529L;
            {
                addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                        slideRight();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        statusPanel.add(new JButton("Slide Up") {
            {
                setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 9204819004142223529L;
            {
                addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                        slideTop();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        statusPanel.add(new JButton("Slide Down") {
            {
                setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 9204819004142223529L;
            {
                addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                        slideBottom();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

public JPanel getBasePanel() {
    return basePanel;
}

private void attach() {
    final ParentType w = this.parent;
    if (w instanceof JFrame) {
        final JFrame j = (JFrame) w;
        if (j.getContentPane().getComponents().length > 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ProgramCheck: Parent already contains content.");
        }
        j.getContentPane().add(basePanel);
    }
    if (w instanceof JDialog) {
        final JDialog j = (JDialog) w;
        if (j.getContentPane().getComponents().length > 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ProgramCheck: Parent already contains content.");
        }
        j.getContentPane().add(basePanel);
    }
    if (w instanceof JWindow) {
        final JWindow j = (JWindow) w;
        if (j.getContentPane().getComponents().length > 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ProgramCheck: Parent already contains content.");
        }
        j.getContentPane().add(basePanel);
    }
    if (w instanceof JPanel) {
        final JPanel j = (JPanel) w;
        if (j.getComponents().length > 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ProgramCheck: Parent already contains content.");
        }
        j.add(basePanel);
    }
}

public void addComponent(final Component component) {
    if (jPanels.contains(component)) {
    }
    else {
        jPanels.add(component);
        if (jPanels.size() == 1) {
            basePanel.add(component);
        }
        component.setSize(basePanel.getSize());
        component.setLocation(0, 0);
    }
}

public void removeComponent(final Component component) {
    if (jPanels.contains(component)) {
        jPanels.remove(component);
    }
}

public void slideLeft() {
    slide(LEFT);
}

public void slideRight() {
    slide(RIGHT);
}

public void slideTop() {
    slide(TOP);
}

public void slideBottom() {
    slide(BOTTOM);
}

private void enableUserInput(final ParentType w) {
    if (w instanceof JFrame) {
        ((JFrame) w).getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
    }
    if (w instanceof JDialog) {
        ((JDialog) w).getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
    }
    if (w instanceof JWindow) {
        ((JWindow) w).getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
    }
}

private void disableUserInput(final ParentType w) {
    if (w instanceof JFrame) {
        ((JFrame) w).setGlassPane(glassPane);
    }
    if (w instanceof JDialog) {
        ((JDialog) w).setGlassPane(glassPane);
    }
    if (w instanceof JWindow) {
        ((JWindow) w).setGlassPane(glassPane);
    }
    glassPane.setVisible(true);
}

private void enableTransparentOverylay() {
    if (parent instanceof JFrame) {
        ((JFrame) parent).getContentPane().setBackground(jPanels.get(0).getBackground());
        parent.remove(basePanel);
        parent.validate();
    }
    if (parent instanceof JDialog) {
        ((JDialog) parent).getContentPane().setBackground(jPanels.get(0).getBackground());
        parent.remove(basePanel);
        parent.validate();
    }
    if (parent instanceof JWindow) {
        ((JWindow) parent).getContentPane().setBackground(jPanels.get(0).getBackground());
        parent.remove(basePanel);
        parent.validate();
    }
}

private void slide(final int slideType) {
    if (!isSlideInProgress) {
        isSlideInProgress = true;
        final Thread t0 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                parent.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
                disableUserInput(parent);
                slide(true, slideType);
                enableUserInput(parent);
                parent.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                isSlideInProgress = false;
            }
        });
        t0.setDaemon(true);
        t0.start();
    }
    else {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}

private void slide(final boolean useLoop, final int slideType) {
    if (jPanels.size() < 2) {
        System.err.println("Not enough panels");
        return;
    }
    synchronized (lock) {
        Component componentOld = null;
        Component componentNew = null;
        if ((slideType == LEFT) || (slideType == TOP)) {
            componentNew = jPanels.remove(jPanels.size() - 1);
            componentOld = jPanels.get(0);
            jPanels.add(0, componentNew);
        }
        if ((slideType == RIGHT) || (slideType == BOTTOM)) {
            componentOld = jPanels.remove(0);
            jPanels.add(componentOld);
            componentNew = jPanels.get(0);
        }
        final int w = componentOld.getWidth();
        final int h = componentOld.getHeight();
        final Point p1 = componentOld.getLocation();
        final Point p2 = new Point(0, 0);
        if (slideType == LEFT) {
            p2.x += w;
        }
        if (slideType == RIGHT) {
            p2.x -= w;
        }
        if (slideType == TOP) {
            p2.y += h;
        }
        if (slideType == BOTTOM) {
            p2.y -= h;
        }
        componentNew.setLocation(p2);
        int step = 0;
        if ((slideType == LEFT) || (slideType == RIGHT)) {
            step = (int) (((float) parent.getWidth() / (float) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width) * 40.f);
        }
        else {
            step = (int) (((float) parent.getHeight() / (float) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height) * 20.f);
        }
        step = step < 5 ? 5 : step;
        basePanel.add(componentNew);
        basePanel.revalidate();
        if (useLoop) {
            final int max = (slideType == LEFT) || (slideType == RIGHT) ? w : h;
            final long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i != (max / step); i++) {
                switch (slideType) {
                    case LEFT: {
                        p1.x -= step;
                        componentOld.setLocation(p1);
                        p2.x -= step;
                        componentNew.setLocation(p2);
                        break;
                    }
                    case RIGHT: {
                        p1.x += step;
                        componentOld.setLocation(p1);
                        p2.x += step;
                        componentNew.setLocation(p2);
                        break;
                    }
                    case TOP: {
                        p1.y -= step;
                        componentOld.setLocation(p1);
                        p2.y -= step;
                        componentNew.setLocation(p2);
                        break;
                    }
                    case BOTTOM: {
                        p1.y += step;
                        componentOld.setLocation(p1);
                        p2.y += step;
                        componentNew.setLocation(p2);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        new RuntimeException("ProgramCheck").printStackTrace();
                        break;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500 / (max / step));
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            final long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        componentOld.setLocation(-10000, -10000);
        componentNew.setLocation(0, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code could be refractored to be a bit cleaner, and the animation is just a bit choppy, but it works and that is impressive. Nice job.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been busy with mid year exams! I'd like to say thank you very much for that code, though it's really long, it works super though!  Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 3):

I have searched for that problem some time ago.I found this sample code somewhere - saved in my evernote for future reference. This is the shortest way to implement that when I googled that in the past

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SlidingPanel {

   JPanel panel;

   public void makeUI() {
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
      panel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);

      JButton button = new JButton("Click");
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
            new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  panel.setLocation(panel.getX() - 1, 0);
                  if (panel.getX() + panel.getWidth() == 0) {
                     ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
               System.out.println("Timer stopped");
            }
               }
            }).start();
         }
      });
      panel.add(button);
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sliding Panel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(400, 400);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setLayout(null);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new SlidingPanel().makeUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```