# How to resize a jpanel when another jpanel is resized

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, layout-manager

It has two JPanels. The first has a sidebar and the other has a title bar.

I want When hiding the first one, the other container to be resized.
For example as in the following image :

Before hiding the Menu:
[image]

After hiding the Menu:
[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: You will need to use the appropriate [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: I could suggest you one thing, whenever you are minimizing the other jpanel at same time you have increase the size of the other panel size(Bigger one). Use it for a temporary work...

Comment: @KumarAnilChaurasiya making one pane grow when another one becomes smaller can be handled automatically by the layout manager.

Comment: Take a look at the first answer to this Stack Overflow question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785804/java-sliding-jpanels

Comment: @c0der, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I think the OP is not after the sliding effect but a simple expand-shrink side panel that can be implemented by using an appropriate layout mannager as demonstrated [here](https://repl.it/repls/LightblueCapitalTerabyte)

Comment: @c0der: Ok.  If the OP clarifies his question, I'll vote to reopen the question.  I interpreted "hiding" to mean sliding.  Perhaps, that's my error.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc see OP's comment